# Why I am losing bytes in data transfer through sockets in this sample?

Tags: c#, winforms, tcpclient

I am trying to receive data asynchronously and store it into StringBuilder and when StringBuilder length will be above 1000 process this data. Every time I call my Update_Interface function some data is lost. I set buffer size to 256. How can I solve this? Its caused because my function need some time to process my data and then Client is not receiving data?

```
 public void Receive(Socket client)
    {

        try
        {
            // Create the state object.  
            StateObject state = new StateObject();
            state.workSocket = client;

            // Begin receiving the data from the remote device.  
            client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }


    }

    public void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {

        try
        {
       

            // Retrieve the state object and the client socket
            // from the asynchronous state object.  
            StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket client = state.workSocket;

            // Read data from the remote device.  
            int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);

            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                // There might be more data, so store the data received so far.  

                state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));


                if (state.sb.Length > 1000)
                {
                    Update_Interface(state.sb.ToString());
                    state.sb.Clear();




                }
                client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                    new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
            }
            else
            {

                receiveDone.Set();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you give us some idea of how you come to determine data is being lost? Is data lost if you convert to something simpler, like Console.WriteLine'ing the sb?

Comment: I determined it becouse I am making live time graph from this data. And my output graph is not the same as a input graph. When I try to comunicate with my server using matlab script its works well but not when trying to implement it into c# code.

Comment: Oh.. I was more hoping you'd show me a screenshot of "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" being written at the server end/appearing ina  telnet, and the c# console writeline looking like "the quck brown fx jumps ovr the lazy do" ...

Comment: Put the BeinReceive and the end of the method.  TCP you can get empty packets before the end of the data.  To know that you are at the end of the data either put a character at the end that is not part of the message or add a byte count at the beginning of the message.  You are also loosing the last part of the message when data is less than 1000 bytes.